# import numpy as np versus from numpy import

Tags: python, numpy, import

I have a module that heavily makes use of `numpy`:

```
from numpy import array, median, nan, percentile, roll, sqrt, sum, transpose, unique, where
```

Is it better practice to keep the namespace clean by using

```
import numpy as np
```

and then when I need to use `array` just use `np.array`, for e.g.?

This module also gets called repeatedly, say a few million times and keeping the namespace clean appears to add a bit of an overhead?

```
setup = '''import numpy as np'''
function = 'x = np.sum(np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]))'
print(min(timeit.Timer(function, setup=setup).repeat(10, 300000)))
```

> **1.66832**

```
setup = '''from numpy import arange, array, sum'''
function = 'x = sum(array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]))'
print(min(timeit.Timer(function, setup=setup).repeat(10, 300000)))
```

> **1.65137**

Why does this add more time when using `np.sum` vs `sum`?

Comment: You might be using default `sum` instead of `np.sum`

Comment: @ycx if OP used `from numpy import sum` it would have shadowed the default `sum`.

Comment: I think the variance is rather small to make this a significant difference.  I think if you run the same line a couple times you will get different results but around the same range regardless.  Also, AFAIK CPU cores do some caching so if it thinks it's doing the same calculation twice, it'll use its cache, I learned this as this was the basis of one of the larger CPU exploits earlier (e.g meltdown).  Try reversing the orders of your tests and see if the second way is consistently lower.

Comment: @Idlehands I obtain the same results *independent* of the order that they are executed in.

Comment: I can confirm that a) the order does not make a difference and b) there is a significant performance difference. I plotted a histogram of the results of both experiments (comparing the minimums is not very good). Results: The "import numpy"-approach is slower and also has a lot more variance. My assumption is that every single time it asks "hey numpy, give me your sum-function please" while the "import functions"-approach directly registers the sum-function in the namespace. But I have no profound knowledge on the actual implementation, so it is just a wild guess.

Comment: And by "significant performance difference" I don't mean "you should never import modules" (I'd always use `import numpy as np`), I just mean "the performance is not the same".

Comment: @niklas-mertsch Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, it is better to keep the namespace clean. So I would use

```
import numpy as np
```

It keeps your code more readable, when you see a call like np.sum(array) you are reminded that you should work with an numpy array. The second reason is that many of the numpy functions have identical names as functions in other modules like scipy... If you use both its always clear which one you are using.

As you you can see in the test you made, the performance difference is there and if you really need the performance you could do it the other way.

The difference in performance is that in the case of a specific function import, you are referencing the function in the numpy module at the beginning of the script. 
In the case of the general module import you import only the reference to the module and python needs to resolve/find the function that you are using in that module at every call.

Answer (score 3):

You could have the best of both worlds (faster name resolution, and non-shadowing), if you're ok with defining your own aliasing (subject to your team conventions, of course):

```
import numpy as np
(np_sum, np_min, np_arange) = (np.sum, np.min, np.arange)

x = np_arange(24)
print (np_sum(x))
```

Alternative syntax to define your aliases:

```
from numpy import \
    arange as np_arange, \
    sum as np_sum, \
    min as np_min
```

Comment: Nice, Can I ask: why `list` over `tuple` though? Any reason for this?

Comment: @ycx: A tuple will do just as well, and is probably more conventional. Perhaps, I should edit :-)